# .htaccess File for Link Shorter Script

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm developing a "Link Shorter Script" with PHP. My shorted links are like this: `/goto.php?id=xxxxx`. I want short links like `http://example.com/xxxxxx`

Can I do it via .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly the kind of thing `RewriteRule`s in .htaccess can be used for. There are several ways to do it which you'll find discussed [numerous times on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20url%20shortener) and [on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+htaccess+url+shortener) but one example is the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /goto.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will match anything upto an optional forward slash, such as `somesite.com/a1b2c3` or `somesite.com/thisisalongstringfortesting/` but not `somesite.com/a/longer/path/`.

There is [thorough documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with examples available which is a good headstart on where you might want to look next.